# Laggy animation on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, animation, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Hi I have got a performance problem that I am unable to solve. Using Blend, I have created an animation showing and hiding a grid. It is invoked when the toggle switch button is checked, and it works. The problem is, that it works really laggy and invokes after a few seconds of delay. I test the application on Nokia Lumia 920. Could you please help me find out what is wrong?

Here is the code of animation, that has been created using blend:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Collapsing">
                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.5" />
                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualState x:Name="Hidden">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="CollapsingGrid">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                  Value="95" />
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5"
                                                  Value="0">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                    <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut" />
                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="anonymousOnLabel">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5"
                                                  Value="0" />
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1"
                                                  Value="91" />
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="SettingsSharePicTglBtn">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                  Value="95" />
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5"
                                                  Value="0" />
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Unhidden">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="CollapsingGrid">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5"
                                                  Value="0" />
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1"
                                                  Value="95">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                    <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut" />
                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="anonymousOnLabel">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                  Value="91" />
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5"
                                                  Value="0" />
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="SettingsSharePicTglBtn">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                  Value="0" />
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5"
                                                  Value="95" />
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

I invoke it the following way:

```
private void TglBtn_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((bool)((ToggleSwitchButton)sender).IsChecked)
            {
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Unhidden", true);
            }
            else
            {
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Hidden", true);
            }
        }
```

Comment: "Works really laggy"? Do you mean that it does not animate smoothly even when it's eventually running?

Comment: Try adding CacheMode="BitmapCache" in xaml to the element you are animating.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson - that is right. The effect is as following: i tap the toggle switch, I have to wait about 0.8 second, the animation of collapse starts, but it is not smooth, and looks as if it was loosing frames.

Comment: @krdx - I guess it might have helped a bit, but it is still not Android/iOS smooth.
My guess is that I have messed something up in the animation, could you help me verify this?

Comment: @krdx Does `BitmapCache` give any effect when animating width and height, forcing a visual tree rebuild? (honest question, I just always assumed it didn't :) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend not animating the **Width** and **Height** properties. Each time these properties change, a full measure/arrange pass is performed on the visual tree, which is very expensive. Instead, you should try animating **Scale** on the grid's RenderTransform from **1.0 to 0.0**.

Now, it's possible you're animating the height because you want things stacked under the grid to move up to fill the space taken up by the grid. In this case, you may need to perform some visual trickery, such as animating **Translate** on the things underneath the grid to move them up, then at the very end of the animation, as the last keyframe, you can reset the RenderTransforms and collapse the grid. Then, you will only suffer a single measure/arrange pass instead of one for each animation frame.

Finally, I would recommend reading up on Windows Phone performance considerations. This is a good document: http://bit.ly/15cExFz

And these two presentations are FANTASTIC. I can't recommend them enough. http://channel9.msdn.com/events/PDC/PDC10/CD03 & http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/3-048

Comment: Your 2nd paragraph was accurate. I have a few elements stacked under the grid, and that was the reason for using Height property. I will check out your solution, and provided materials, and will come back with an answer whether this solved the problem. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problem, but I have animated RotationX, RotationY properties of PlaneProjection using DoubleAnimation. The solution of problem have been found from this [article](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/08/performanceprogressbar/). And it was adding of "magic" numbers ending in 0.1 – that tells the system it’s a ratio based on the width of the control, it's hack overload of a property but it gives real performance grow in some cases.

```
<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="anonymousOnLabel">
    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0.1" />
    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="91.1" />
</DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

And of course it not good idea to animate Width and Height properties directly because it will be Dependant Animation and will have performance impact.